# Geolocalização e requisições HTTP em segundo plano com Ionic 2

Tags: android, ios, http, ionic2, geolocalização

Estou criando uma aplicação com o **Ionic 2** nessa aplicação eu preciso pegar a geolocalização do dispositivo e fazer requisições HTTP para um web service que tenho públicado.

Usei o SQLite para guardar as informações enquanto estava offline, e enviar quando estiver online. Até ai beleza! O problema é que quando estou no IOs ou no Android se eu aperto a tecla "home" ou bloqueio os dispositivos simplesmente para de gravar a geolocalização do dispositivo e também para de fazer as requisições HTTP. Porém é importante que enquanto tenha conexão essas informações sejam enviadas, mesmo com o dispositivo bloqueado ou com a aplicação "minimizada".

Estudei plugins do ionic-native como o BackgroundMode, e o BackgroundGeolocation mas não funcionou. No caso do backgroundMode ele simplemente não funciona no IOs, e o BackgroundGeolocation mesmo que ele capture a geolocalização e guarde no SQLite não é feito a execução das chamadas HTTP.

Alguém sabe como posso tratar isso? Estou fazendo uso do IONIC VIEW para efetuar os testes.

Obrigado!